# How do you process Tar Files in memory using BytesIO or StringIO (Python)?

Tags: python

I am using `requests` to get a `.tar.gz` object.

Ie. I run

```
response = requests.get(DOWNLOAD_URL)
```

and the contents of the response are the bytes in a `.tar.gz` file.

I could do

```
import tarfile

with open('tmp.tar.gz', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response.content)

answer = {}

with tarfile.open('tmp.tar.gz') as tar:
    for member in tar:
        if member.name != '.':
            answer[member.name] = tar.extractfile(member).read()
            
# contents are in `answer`
answer
```

But I don't think the round trip to the hard drive is 100% necessary. I was trying to get this to work using either `io.BytesIO` or `io.StringIO`, but can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

`tarfile.open` can take a `fileobj` keyword argument to specify the `BytesIO` object to work with.

```
with tarfile.open(fileobj=io.BytesIO(response.content)) as tar:
```

---

(Strictly speaking, you could use a positional argument, too, but then you'd have to explicitly provide `None` as the file name and a mode argument, like

```
tarfile.open(None, 'r', BytesIO(response.content)
```

but ugh, who wants to do that?)